# Dupe of deleted question

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29531/what-are-some-good-programming-exercises-projects-to-help-me-learn-new-languages?rq=1) is marked as a dupe of a deleted question.

Please unmark it as dupe, or resurrect the deleted question.

Comment: You should just flag the question for moderator attention.

Comment: D'oh. I thought Meta is the way to go. Thanks, I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great example for where a moderator flag is appropriate.

[image]

---

This will help explain what happened.
The question you linked was closed a while back.

[image]

And the question it was closed against as duplicate was deleted more recently.

[image]

---

If nothing else, you can say that you have found evidence to prove it's always Jeff's fault when things go wrong.  :-)

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed] - the question in question has been (deservedly) deleted